# error when i run my RMI project

Tags: netbeans, rmi

what do i have to do when I have this error:

> java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
>           java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

I added the path of the bin in JDK in the properties of "MY computer": this one "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\bin"

and I entered to run-cmd-

```
cd C:\Users\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CountRMI\src\countrmi 
start rmiregistry
```

and i run the server, so this error appear

> java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
>           java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Thank u

Answer (score 0):

Consider looking at the [Cajo project](http://java.net/projects/cajo/pages/Home). It wraps RMI so you don't have to worry about starting rmi registries and the such. 
See the example below from one of the Cajo [wiki pages](http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Communications/TransparentProxy)

**Duck.java**

```
public interface Duck {
   boolean looks();
   boolean walks();
   boolean talks();
}
```

**DuckServer.java**

```
import gnu.cajo.invoke.Remote;
import gnu.cajo.utils.ItemServer;

public class DuckServer implements Duck {
   public boolean looks()  {
      System.out.println("hi there!");
      return true;
   }
   public boolean walks()  {
      System.out.println("waddle waddle");
      return true;
   }
   public boolean talks() {
      System.out.println("quack quack!");
      return true;
   }
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception { // simple unit test
      Remote.config(null, 1198, null, 0); // use cajo port 1198
      ItemServer.bind(new DuckServer(), "Donald");
      System.out.println("duck server running");
   }
}
```

**DuckClient.java**

```
import gnu.cajo.utils.extra.TransparentItemProxy;

public class DuckClient { // try out DuckServer
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
      Duck duck = (Duck)TransparentItemProxy.getItem(
         "//serverHost:1198/Donald",
         new Class[] { Duck.class }
      );
      System.out.println("looks like = " + duck.looks());
      System.out.println("walks like = " + duck.walks());
      System.out.println("talks like = " + duck.talks());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The time has passed, but maybe this helps someone. When you put

```
cd C:\Users\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CountRMI\src\countrmi
```

you are setting de path to sources files, but yo have to set this to the classes files, in this way

```
cd C:\Users\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CountRMI\build\classes
```

and start `rmiregistry`, of course

at least, it worked fine for me.